# Navbar dropdown cart on constant loop of requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a React e-commerce project. I'm currently working on a Navbar Cart, but it's constantly sending thousands of requests per minute whenever I check Chrome Devtool. I usually use useEffect for this type of queries, and I tried it and placed it outside of the condition, but it'd show the previous user's cart on initial login unless I refresh the page after logging in.

What can I do so that it's dynamic and changes only when there's a newly added cart item, and not a constant loop of requests?

**No useEffect -- it works but there's a constant loop of requests**

```
const AppNavbar = (props) => {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])
    let navigation 

    if (user.token === null) {
        navigation = (
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/register">Register</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        )
    } else {
        if (user.role === 'admin') {
            navigation = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Menu</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/logout">Logout</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        } else {
            GQLClient({}).request(Query.getUserCart, { id: user.id }).then( ({getUserCart}) => {
                setCartItems(getUserCart.map( (cart) => 
                    <NavDropdown.Item key={cart._id}>
                        <Button type="button" onClick={ (e) => deleteCart(e, cart.id) } variant="danger" className="p-1">x</Button>
                        {cart.activityName}
                    </NavDropdown.Item>  
                ))
            })

            navigation = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Menu</Nav.Link>
                        <NavDropdown title="Following">
                            {cartItems}
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <Nav.Link className="text-info" href="/follow-list">View Detailed List</Nav.Link>
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <Nav.Link href="/transactions">Transactions</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/logout">Logout</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
```

**with useEffect -- no more request loop, but displays previous user's cart. unless refreshed after login**

```
const AppNavbar = (props) => {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])
    let navigation 

    useEffect( () => {
        if (user.role === 'customer'){
            GQLClient({}).request(Query.getUserCart, { id: user.id }).then( ({getUserCart}) => {
                setCartItems(getUserCart.map( (cart) => 
                    <NavDropdown.Item key={cart._id}>
                        <Button type="button" onClick={ (e) => deleteCart(e, cart.id) } variant="danger" className="p-1">x</Button>
                        {cart.activityName}
                    </NavDropdown.Item>  
                ))
            })
        }
    }, [])

    if (user.token === null) {
        navigation = (
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/register">Register</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        )
    } else {
        if (user.role === 'admin') {
            navigation = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Menu</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/logout">Logout</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        } else {
            navigation = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Menu</Nav.Link>
                        <NavDropdown title="Following">
                            {cartItems}
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <Nav.Link className="text-info" href="/follow-list">View Detailed List</Nav.Link>
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <Nav.Link href="/transactions">Transactions</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/logout">Logout</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the previous code that used `useEffect`? That code sounds closer to correct than this code.

Comment: Although one quick fix you could try is to only do the request if `carItems` was empty. As it stands, you have a loop because you do the request on _every_ render, and that request _always_ changes the cart items, which triggers a render, which triggers a request, etc.

Comment: Hello Garrett. I've edited the post and added the useEffect attempt. Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you are rendering this component in another component that has the user context, right? So what you want to happen is to invalidate all subcomponent state whenever the user changes, correct?

Comment: Yes, I call the Navbar component in App.js, which is where the root of user state is  as well as the routers for my pages.

Yes, however I think the useEffect delays it which I think is why the initial login is displaying the previous user's cart. Unless I refresh after logging in

Comment: Could you also provide the code that populates the user id? (and other info)